# Difference between IntelliJ IDEA versions "Linux" and "Linux, without JDK"

Tags: intellij-idea

When downloading IntelliJ IDEA, there are [two options for Linux](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/?fromMenu#chooseYourEdition):

[image: IntelliJ IDEA Download Options]

I assume the *Linux (.tar.gz)* version comes with a JDK and the *Linux, without JDK (.tar.gz)* version does not. However, when reading the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/sdk.html) I see:

> IntelliJ IDEA does not include an SDK. So, before you start writing your code, you have to download and install at least one SDK and define it in IntelliJ IDEA.

So what exactly is the difference between the two versions? And if one comes with a JDK, which JDK does it come with?

Comment: This is the link - for users that don't have Linux - to see the picture above: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the JDK IntelliJ IDEA itself runs on. To quote a related [support document](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under):

> Starting from IntelliJ IDEA 16 and the most recent versions of the lightweight IDEs, we are bundling custom JRE with Linux distributions, just like we've been doing for Mac. Our custom JRE is based on OpenJDK and includes the most up to date fixes to provide better user experience on Linux (like font rendering improvements and HiDPI support).

For your own projects you will probably want to use an official and supported Oracle JDK.

Comment: Why do you want to use the Oracle JDK for your own projecs? is OpenJDK not good? Why not in your opinion?

Comment: this would be very interesting. :-)